# How to resize QTableWidgetItem to its editor size then to its text size using QStyledItemDelegate?

Tags: pyqt5, size, pyside2, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate

I created my own `CustomDelegate` class derived from `QStyledItemDelegate`:

```
class CustomDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QWidget(parent)
        editor_hlayout = QHBoxLayout(editor)
        button = QPushButton()
        line_edit = QLineEdit()
        editor_hlayout.addWidget(button)
        editor_hlayout.addWidget(line_edit)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        model_data = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
        editor.layout().itemAt(1).widget().setText(model_data) # Set line_edit value

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        editor_data =  editor.layout().itemAt(1).widget().text() # Get line_edit value
        model.setData(index, editor_data, Qt.EditRole)
        
    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)
```

I set it for the last column of the QTableWidget my_table :

```
my_delegate = CustomDelegate(my_window)
my_table.setItemDelegateForColumn(my_table.columnCount()-1, my_delegate)
```

To be precise, my goal is to edit the table widget item size when double-clicking it so that it fits the editor size and properly displays it, then edit the table widget item size right after exiting editor mode so that it fits its text size back again.

To that end, I added the lines `index.model().setData(index, editor.sizeHint(), Qt.SizeHintRole)` in `createEditor` method and `model.setData(index, QTableWidgetItem(editor_data).sizeHint(), Qt.SizeHintRole)` in `setModelData` method.

The problem is that `QTableWidgetItem(editor_data).sizeHint()` returns (-1, -1) size. I also tried with QTextDocument(editor_data).size() but it does not fit the text width (it is slightly smaller).

- How to get the good text size hint ?
- Also, somebody told me about reducing the editor minimum size hint to avoid editing the QTableWidgetItem size at all. Does it solve my problem and how to perform it ?

Comment: Why are you still trying to resize the index, while you only need to resize the editor?

Comment: @musicamante Because the answer can still be helpful if the editor is tall. Please also note I took your suggestion into account: see my second question.

Comment: If the editor requires more space, then allow it in `updateEditorGeometry`, by checking if the size hint of the editor is bigger than the option rect and eventually use the one that fits your needs. As already said in my other comments, the size of the editor should not change the size of the index, especially if the editor is not persistent.

Comment: @musicamante By doing so, the editor would exceed cell delimitations, but I agree it is better than nothing. So, as you do not suggest to resize the item, how do you resize the editor so that it displays properly ? Could you give me the method(s) to use ?

Comment: @Skryge What do you expect to happen if the text is longer than the item-rect? What if the text extends beyond the last column, or beyond the edge of the view, or is wider than the entire view? What happens when the user starts editing - should the line-edit grow/shrink accordingly? If you experiment with the built-in editor, you will see that it handles all of these scenarios, but *never* by adjusting the view-item itself. Really, it's up to you to calculate the correct size and set it inside `updateEditorGeometry`. There's no method that will do it all for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor of a item view should not change the size of its index. The only cases for which this is considered valid is for *persistent* editors and index widgets, but due to their nature it makes sense: they are expected to persist on the view, and not only it's acceptable that they require the view to eventually expand their row or column, but also necessary in order to avoid editors hiding other items (or editors).

Any change in the section sizes can be potentially very demanding to the view, especially if it has lots of data and any of the header uses the `ResizeToContents` mode, that's why the default factory editors (QLineEdit, QDate/TimeEdit and Q[Double]SpinBox) don't update the index sizes but eventually extend their geometry temporarily.

I would suggest to follow this practice, and eventually update the geometry in `updateEditorGeometry()` according to the editor position.

In order to optimize the available space, you could use some precautions:

- explicitly set 0 margins for the layout;
- minimize the spacing between widgets;
- disable the frame of the QLineEdit (as the default editor does);
- use QToolButton instead of QPushButton, since it can usually be made smaller than the latter; this also makes it easier some focus aspects, as QToolButton doesn't accept focus by clicking;

Also note that:

- the editor should use `setAutoFillBackground(True)` otherwise parts of the underlying items might be visible;
- the line edit should probably have the focus on default, you can use [`setFocusProxy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocusProxy) on the editor, so that the line edit gets focused when the parent does;
- you should not use the layout to access the line edit, instead create a reference for it in the editor object;
- if you still want to make the editor border visible, use a proper stylesheet;

```py
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QWidget(parent)
        editor.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        editor_hlayout = QHBoxLayout(editor)
        editor_hlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        editor_hlayout.setSpacing(1)
        button = QToolButton()
        editor.line_edit = QLineEdit(frame=False)
        editor_hlayout.addWidget(button)
        editor_hlayout.addWidget(editor.line_edit)
        editor.setFocusProxy(editor.line_edit)

        # eventually (see note)
        editor.setObjectName('delegateEditor')
        editor.setStyleSheet('''
            #delegateEditor {
                border: 1px solid palette(mid); 
                background: palette(base);
            }
        ''')
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        model_data = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
        editor.line_edit.setText(model_data)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        editor_data =  editor.line_edit.text()
        model.setData(index, editor_data, Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        super().updateEditorGeometry(editor, option, index)
        editor.resize(editor.sizeHint().width(), editor.height())
        rect = editor.geometry()
        parentRect = editor.parent().rect()
        if not parentRect.contains(rect):
            if rect.right() > parentRect.right():
                rect.moveRight(parentRect.right())
            if rect.x() < parentRect.x():
                rect.moveLeft(parentRect.x())
            if rect.bottom() > parentRect.bottom():
                rect.moveBottom(parentRect.bottom())
            if rect.y() < parentRect.y():
                rect.moveTop(parentRect.y())
            editor.setGeometry(rect)
```

Note: if you do use stylesheets, it's possible that the line edit will partially draw over the border; in that case, use `editor_hlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 1, 0)`.

---

That said, if you really want to update the view sizes, you still can, but it can be a bit tricky.

The trick is to keep track of the editor and its index, manually resize the sections in order to fit its size, and then restore those sizes when the editor is destroyed.

```py
class CustomDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.editorData = {}
        super().__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QWidget(parent)
        editor.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        editor_hlayout = QHBoxLayout(editor)
        editor_hlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        editor_hlayout.setSpacing(1)
        button = QToolButton()
        editor.line_edit = QLineEdit(frame=False)
        editor_hlayout.addWidget(button)
        editor_hlayout.addWidget(editor.line_edit)
        editor.setFocusProxy(editor.line_edit)
        view = option.widget
        # store the editor, the view and also the current sizes
        self.editorData[index] = (editor, view, 
            view.horizontalHeader().sectionSize(index.column()), 
            view.verticalHeader().sectionSize(index.row())
            )
        # THEN, resize the row and column, which will call sizeHint()
        view.resizeColumnToContents(index.column())
        view.resizeRowToContents(index.row())
        # delay a forced scroll to the index to ensure that the editor is
        # visible after the sections have been resized
        QTimer.singleShot(1, lambda: view.scrollTo(index))
        return editor

    def sizeHint(self, opt, index):
        if index in self.editorData:
            # sizeHint doesn't provide access to the editor
            editor, *_ = self.editorData[index]
            return editor.sizeHint()
        return super().sizeHint(opt, index)

    def destroyEditor(self, editor, index):
        super().destroyEditor(editor, index)
        if index in self.editorData:
            editor, view, width, height = self.editorData.pop(index)
            view.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(index.column(), width)
            view.verticalHeader().resizeSection(index.row(), height)
```

Note that if the index is near the edge (last row or column), when the editor is destroyed it's possible that the view won't properly adjust its scroll bars if the scroll mode is `ScrollPerItem`. AFAIK there's no easy workaround for this.

Remember what said above, though. As [Ian Malcolm would say](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3j9muCo4o0), whether this could be done or not, you should stop and think if you should.

### Update about focus issues

As pointed out in comments, if the user clicks somewhere else when the editor is active, the editor doesn't close itself as expected.

By default, the delegate's event filter closes the editor whenever it loses focus, but the filter is set on the editor, not its children. When the line edit receives focus, the event filter recognizes that the new focus widget is a child of the editor and will not close it; this is important, because if the editor has child widgets, you don't want it to close just because the internal focus has changed; the side effect of this is that when clicking outside of the line edit, it is the line edit that will receive the `FocusOut` event, not the editor, so the event filter won't know nothing about it; note that this also happens even when using `setFocusProxy()`, as Qt automatically sends focus events to the proxy.

There are at least two possible solutions for this, depending on the editor type.

If there is going to be just *one* main child widget that should accept focus like in this case, the solution is to do what other complex widgets (like QComboBox and QAbstractSpinBox): set the editor as focus proxy of the widget, and post the related events to the widget in the event filter:

```py
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        # ...
        editor.line_edit.setFocusProxy(editor)

    def eventFilter(self, editor, event):
        if event.type() in (
            event.FocusIn, event.FocusOut, 
            event.KeyPress, event.KeyRelease, 
            event.ShortcutOverride, event.InputMethod, 
            event.ContextMenu
            ):
                editor.line_edit.event(event)
                if event.type() != event.FocusOut:
                    return event.isAccepted()
        return super().eventFilter(editor, event)
```

For more complex situations, we need to ensure that the default implementation of the delegate event filter receives a focus out event whenever the focus is completely lost by the editor or any of its children.

In order to achieve this, a possible solution is to create a custom object that will become an event filter for **all** child widgets of the editor and eventually *posts* a `FocusOut` event for the editor whenever the focused widget is not itself or one of its children (including grandchildren).

```py
class FocusOutFilter(QObject):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self.widget = widget
        self.install(widget)

    def install(self, widget):
        widget.installEventFilter(self)
        for child in widget.findChildren(QWidget):
            child.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (event.type() == event.FocusOut and
            not self.widget.isAncestorOf(QApplication.focusWidget())):
                obj.removeEventFilter(self)
                self.deleteLater()
                return QApplication.sendEvent(self.widget, event)
        elif event.type() == event.ChildAdded:
            self.install(event.child())
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class CustomDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    # ...
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QWidget(parent)
        editor.filter = FocusOutFilter(editor)
        # ...
```

There is a catch. The problem is that `focusWidget()` will return the widget even if the event results in opening a menu. While this is fine for any context menu of the editor widgets (including the edit menu of QLineEdit), it could create some issues when the view implements the context menu event (showing a menu in `contextMenuEvent()`, within a `ContextMenu` event or with `CustomContextMenu` policy). There is no final solution for this, as there is no definite way to check *what* created the menu: a proper implementation expects that a QMenu is created with the parent that created it, but that cannot be certain (for simplicity, dynamically created menus could be created without any parent, which makes it impossible to know *what* created them). In these cases, the simplest solution is to implement the above conditions by first checking the return value of [`isPersistentEditorOpen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#isPersistentEditorOpen) *and* ensure that [`widgetAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#widgetAt) properly returns the table's `viewport()`.

Comment: @musicamente Thank you so much for your answer in addition to the useful tips you taught me ! Now that I see the result, I agree with you that the 1st solution is better from every point of view. If I understood your 2nd solution correctly, you do not take into account the new text width (when adding some text to the line edit for example) when destroying editor, so my initial problem would still apply with 2nd solution anyway.

Comment: @musicamente Could you please explain the `updateEditorGeometry` part (in particular the if statements) ? When using it I end up with the editor being smaller than the item so that the right part of the item text is not hidden by the `setAutoFillBackground` method. It seems that not overriding the `updateEditorGeometry` method simply does the job. Also, just note that you forgot to add `return editor` in `createEditor` method.

Comment: @Skryge you're welcome! 1. yes, you're right, the 2nd solution doesn't consider the (possibly) new size, a further complex checking of each header resize mode would be necessary, further complicating the concept - another reason to avoid it ;-) ; 2. the ifs in `updateEditorGeometry()` are to ensure that the editor is fully visible in the view, which is extremely important when the item is not fully visible due to scrolling; you could use `max` for editor *and* `option.rect` dimensions: `editor.resize(max(editor.sizeHint().width(), option.rect.width()), editor.height())`; 3. fixed, thanks.

Comment: @musicamente It seems that one default behavior is still missing : editor is not destroyed when clicking outside the table (outside the cells but still in the table model, I do not know how to define this location). Do you know what I should do ?

Comment: @Skryge You are right, and that's an important issue. Sorry if I didn't answer immediately, but I had to find enough time to properly focus on it. See the update; I'm not completely sure that it properly addresses any user case, but it's a start. Working with complex delegate editors is not easy, and my comments to this and your previous posts were based on that acknowledgement (I know I may have been a bit unfriendly, but we don't always have the time to be that thorough in our replies). That said, I'd ask you to carefully test the above update, and eventually provide some feedback.

Comment: Thank you (again) for your very complete answer ! Your first solution shall fit my current needs but I will keep your second solution in mind for the future. If I understand correctly, focus is set first on line_edit then on editor via `editor.line_edit.setFocusProxy(editor)` (without exiting the 'visual' line edit focus). If this is correct, could you explain how it is done step by step ?

Comment: Also, I am sorry to mention it only now, but my editor's tool button is connected to a function that uses `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` to select a file then `line_edit.setText(path)` to add its path to the editor's line edit. Unfortunatly, the line edit is destroyed (by eventFilter I guess) before `line_edit.setText` is called. I think I can roughly solve it by handling the exception raised but maybe would you have a proper suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, you should have mentioned that earlier. The editor is indeed destroyed because the filter detects a `FocusOut` event, just like clicking outside of it: while that event has a [`reason()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfocusevent.html#reason) there's no specific distinction for a focus lost from another window. I believe it's possible to fix that too, but it complicates things and the solution completely depends on which approach you used from those suggested above. Be aware, this is becoming *very* off topic: you asked about editor resizing; I believe you should probably create a new question.

Comment: About your other comment: the focus is not "set first on line_edit then on editor"; `setFocusProxy` doesn't set the focus, but sets the "focus manager" of a widget onto another. In the case of `editor.line_edit.setFocusProxy(editor)` it means that whenever the line edit gets focused, the actual *focus widget* will be the editor. Note that this might be counterintuitive: it's important that, programmatically, the "focus widget" is the editor, even if the widget that *actually* has focus is another; this is what Qt does for complex widgets like QAbstractSpinBox or editable QComboBoxes: they ->

Comment: -> both have a child QLineEdit, but whenever you want to know the focus widget you are generally not interested in that line edit but in the spin/combo box. Since the delegate's event filter is only installed on the editor (not its children), it *must* receive focus events "delivered" from the children: if the line edit loses focus, the proxy (the editor) will receive the event, and then we are able to properly *filter* that event. As said, it's a bit difficult and counterintuitive (I know, it took me a while to get it); I suggest you to do some experiments on your own to better understand it.

Comment: Thanks for invoking the `reason` method! It turns out that clicking on the tool button triggers `ActiveWindowFocusReason` reason whereas clicking outside the table triggers `MouseFocusReason` reason.  Also, I realized returning `event.isAccepted()` when `event.type() != event.FocusOut` prevents some default behaviors from occurring (when pressing Escape/Enter/Return buttons for example). Replacing `if event.type() != event.FocusOut:` with `if event.type() == event.FocusOut and event.reason() != Qt.FocusReason.MouseFocusReason:` in your first solution seems to solve these 2 issues.

Comment: That makes me wondering : 1. What is the point of returning `event.isAccepted()` almost in any case? Can `return super().eventFilter(editor, event)` imply unwanted behavior when event type is not FocusOut ?
2. Why return `event.isAccepted()`? Is this boolean used for something useful?
3. How is it decided whether `event.isAccepted()` is True or False ?

Comment: Here is what I meant by "set first on line_edit then on editor" : when the `eventFilter` method detects editor's FocusIn event, it emulates FocusIn event on the line edit via `editor.line_edit.event(event)` (this is my understanding of this line, please feel free to let me know if I am wrong) so that the focus is 'visually' and 'internally' set on the line edit. But due to `editor.line_edit.setFocusProxy(editor)`, the focus is 'internally' (but not 'visually') set back to the editor. Is is correct ?

Comment: Note that using `ActiveWindowFocusReason` alone might not suffice: it doesn't tell if the window focus change is caused by *your* dialog or just because the user switched to a window of another program (or minimized the window with the table). The return of `object.event(event)` might not always coincide with the event's accepted "state": it **usually** returns `True` if the event was recognized and processed, but the event might still be "ignored". This might be necessary for events that should be handled by a child object but *also* by any of its parents. Depending on the combination of ->

Comment: widget and event type, the result can vary. For instance, some widgets handle mouse events (in the meaning that they react to those events in some way) but set it as ignored as it may be necessary for the parent to actually process that event and decide if accept it or not. Returning `True` from an event filter means that the event will then *not* be handled by the object's `event()` (it has been *filtered*): if it has been accepted, that object's `event()` will *not* be called. Your last comment is correct.

Comment: After reading the docs, I believe the `event.isAccepted` method is used in the default `QWidget::event` implementation to decide whether returning `True` (i.e. event won't be propagated to the parent widget) or `False` before ` QApplication::notify` gets called. As the `eventFilter` and `event` methods' returned values achieve completely different goals, I do not understand why returning `event.isAccepted()` in the `eventFilter` method would be of any use/sense. -->

Comment: And the `eventFilter` method is called before the`event` method so the event handler did not indicate to the `event` method whether accepting or not the event yet anyway. Also, it turns out that returning `event.isAccepted()` has the same effect than returning `True` or `False`. That makes me suspect that the returned value is not the only condition for the editor to decide whether calling or not its `event` method. Do you agree ? We can talk about it elsewhere if it does not bother you.

Comment: I was wrong : as you said, the value returned by `eventFilter` tells if the `event` method is called or not. However, when event type is `FocusOut`, the default `eventFilter` method call imply `closeEditor` method call. I think this is the only reason why the editor is usually closed when event type is `FocusOut`. Hence, returning `False` will allow the `FocusOut` event to be processed but it will not actually cause the editor to close (as well as returning `True` or `event.isAccepted()`). I would rather return `True` to avoid any confusion between `eventFilter` and `event` methods.

Comment: @Skryge https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243024/